# Laravel guzzleHttp - two laravel application - checking model in client side

Tags: php, laravel

I have two Laravel applications hosting on the same XAMPP server.

For the first Laravel application I used a guzzle http request to get data.

```
$res = $clients->request('POST', $api_url.'api/createJob', [
           'form_params' => [
               'app_id' => $app_id,
               'data' => $jobData,
               'first_name' => \Auth::user()->first_name,
               'last_name' => \Auth::user()->last_name,
               'email' => \Auth::user()->email
           ]
       ]);
```

For the second Laravel application I wrote an API to return data

```
$data = DB::table('contacts')
          ->where('id', '1')
          ->first();

$result = [
    'status' => 'success',
    'data' => $data,
    'message' => 
    'Success' 
];

return json_encode($result);
```

The problem is, it's showing 500 internal error like base table not found. 
It means it's looking for a table in the first Laravel application and not in the second Laravel application.

But its works in post man.

Comment: Which applications throws the 500 response? Is your logging configured? Then have a look to your php or application error log. Base table not found could be caused by not running an artisan migrate which has also happened to me

Comment: First laravel application which have guzzleHttp request throws 500 error. Because contacts table available only in second laravel application. 

Note: if without using db query in second application..  it gives response properly.. but if i write any query then it look data in client side application not in second laravel application. Because of this problem i checked with post man.. their it gives correct response.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i got solution for this.

In both laravel application .env file has same variable name for db connection. I have changed one of the connection as below.

```
DB_HOST_1=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_1=3306
DB_DATABASE_1=db_name
DB_USERNAME_1=root
DB_PASSWORD_1=
```

Now, its working fine.